# how to resolve Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to submit a form to a database using Laravel 5.4 but each time I press the submit button I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found.

Below is my code for `controller.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('./');
    }

    public function about()
    {
        $title='About us';
        return view('pages.about')->with('title',$title);
    }

    public function services()
    {
        $data=array(
            'title'=>'Services',
            'services'=>['Mechanic help','book a mechanic','others']
        );
        return view('pages.services')->with ($data);
    }

    public function create()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly spend some time in formatting the question

Comment: Well, what class are you *trying* to extend exactly? Apparently not `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`…

Comment: 'controller.php'. Is that the name of the file, and is it in the `app/Http/Controllers` directory?

Comment: Use this below namespace `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: @Rits It's already trying to load `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`, there is no additional alias needed for that name.

Comment: Let's see your form data. I need to see the URL for your submit.

Comment: But try for once you are just extending controller class its saying that that class not found if you use that then it find a path for that

Comment: Its your `PagesController.php` file right???

Comment: @Rits `use` doesn't do anything useful to enable PHP to find a class it already knows about.

Comment: Okay no problem sorry

Answer (score 1):

That kind of error would mean that you are either missing your Controller.php file in the same folder, or the autoloader isn't loading it, or it is not defining the class Controller. This is the file in the Laravel repo:

https://github.com/laravel-shift/laravel-5.4/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

Answer (score 1):

> Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found.

This error could only mean that you are missing this class. Make sure that you have a `Controller.php` in the same folder with your `PagesController.php`. Also, kindly check if you are using the right namespace and be strict with capitalizations.

Comment: it is in the same folder as PagesController.php, but I still get that error message

Comment: Your controllers filenamae and class name should be the same. Say for ex. your PagesController class should be named `PagesController.php`